# If you update a routes file in Drupal 8 how do you clear the cache?

Tags: caching, 8, routes

Having worked with Drupal 7 since its launch, I'm learning Drupal 8. At the moment I'm finding that whenever I change anything I have to do `drush cache-rebuild` to get things working again.

On my VPS this takes 15 seconds (and then the next page load also is slow). I have a feeling this may be a sledge hammer to crack a nut situation.

Is there a more efficient way to get Drupal to recompile the (changed) routes from `{module}.routing.yml` files?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use

```
drush ev '\Drupal::service("router.builder")->rebuild();'
```

to rebuild the routing information without clearing all the caches.

Comment: Handy. Only takes 3.5s, a big improvement, many thanks. Shame there's not a drush command for this.

Comment: Pretty sure that a PR to add a drush cc something would be a accepted, it's a common use case. Or maybe as part of "drush cc menu", which already exists but likely doesn't do much in D8.

Comment: @Berdir This looks relevant? but it doesn't do the same as this answer says: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/commit/82c6ef119b2396350bfed8a2b4d10e20922097f0

Comment: Related, but that just invalidates the menu links, so it's about links.menu.yml. Seems like it should also cover the routes, local tasks and local actions.

Comment: Good idea berdir!

Comment: is there no other options than drush or drupal console?

Comment: For those individuals landing here from a internet search, checkout RouterBuilder::setRebuildNeeded() if looking to clear route cache programmatically as part of code execution. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21RouteBuilderInterface.php/function/RouteBuilderInterface%3A%3AsetRebuildNeeded/

Answer (score 9):

An alternative to drush is [drupal console](http://drupalconsole.com/), which you can then use as:

```
drupal router:rebuild
```

Which is a little less typing than the `drush ev` answer (and a tinsy bit faster, too).

To install drupal console

```
curl -LSs http://drupalconsole.com/installer | php
mv console.phar /path/to/a/suitable/bin/drupal
```

Answer (score 9):

```
drush cc router
```

when using drush 9 do the trick now :-)

Comment: Thanks @andsigno82 it's working well for me